# Android execute a notification action with NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a NotificationListenerService class, which can read active notifications in the system.

All necessary permission are set, everything works as intended.

One easy question come however to me.

There is a notification with actions:

[image]

How can I "push" these buttons programmatically?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't yet found anything unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to check the fields of `Notification`, where all `Notification.Action`s are defined.

So you can get their `actionIntent` and simply send it:

```
public static class MyNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    public MyNotificationListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        try {
          sbn.getNotification().actions[0].actionIntent.send();
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Idea came from here: [How to cancel an ongoing notification of another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587436/how-to-cancel-an-ongoing-notification-of-another-app)